# 'Media' object has no attribute 'render_styles'

Tags: python, node.js, django, sass

I am getting this error when I try to go to the Django admin category page.

my grunt.js page:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        sass: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    style: 'compressed'
                },
                files: {
                    'static/styles/css/style.css': 'media/assets/styles/sass/style.scss'
                }
            }
        },
        watch: {
            sass: {
                files: ['media/assets/styles/sass/*.scss'],
                tasks: ['sass:dist']
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-autoprefixer');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['sass:dist']);
};
```

When I try to go to the django admin, I have no problem but when try to go to the category page or user page, I got this error:

```
AttributeError at /admin/bookmark/category/
'Media' object has no attribute 'render_styles'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/admin/bookmark/category/
Django Version: 4.0.3
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'Media' object has no attribute 'render_styles'
Exception Location: C:\Users\moust\Workspace\python_projects\saas_app\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py, line 97, in <genexpr>
Python Executable:  C:\Users\moust\Workspace\python_projects\saas_app\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.5
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\moust\\Workspace\\python_projects\\saas_app',
 'c:\\users\\moust\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\python39.zip',
 'c:\\users\\moust\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\DLLs',
 'c:\\users\\moust\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib',
 'c:\\users\\moust\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39',
 'C:\\Users\\moust\\Workspace\\python_projects\\saas_app\\venv',
 'C:\\Users\\moust\\Workspace\\python_projects\\saas_app\\venv\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Sun, 17 Apr 2022 05:14:14 +0000
```

[this is the suit of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxOxw.png)